# Show that the following Sets have Lebesgue_Measure Zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to show that the following two sets have Lebesgue-Measure Zero.

1.) The graph($f$) in $\mathbb R^2$ if $f$ is given as $f:\left[ 0,1 \right] \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

2.)$\left\{ (x,y,z):\quad x+y+z=0 \right\} \quad in\ \mathbb R^3$.

What's need to be done is to find open Cubes so that the Sum over the Volume of those open Cubes is smaller than an abitrary Epsilon.
And I'm havin struggels to construct those open Cubes.

Comment: For (1), do you assume the function is continuous?

Comment: yes i do! sorry for not pointing out

Comment: For (1), can you cover with closed rectangles? Can you describe what it might look like, and how might you use continuity (or uniform continuity)?

Comment: Yes we can cover with ractangels, since we'r looking for the Sum over the volume of thos rectangles we can use the volumen formula. ${ (\frac { a*b }{ 2 } +1) }_{ i }$ (i is just the index for summation) dividing it by two assures that the rectangles dont get two big and the +1 since we are continous. Its just a guess Im not that good at constructing things

Comment: I did not understand your "$+1$" in the formula "$(\frac{ab}{2} +1)_i$."  It may help to remember that for integration we chop the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ slices of size $\delta=1/n$ and we have rectangles of width $\delta$ and height $f(x_i)$.  Here we are not integrating, so we only want the "tips" of those rectangles.  If we look at the point $(x_i,f(x_i))$, how can we construct a small rectangle that contains $(x,f(x))$ for all $x \in [x_i, x_i+\delta]$ (for some $\delta>0$ that possibly depends on the height of the rectangle)?  You can use uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: The only rectangle that would make sense to me is $\frac { f({ x }_{ i }+\delta )-f({ x }_{ i }) }{ ({ x }_{ i }+\delta )-({ x }_{ i }) } $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67614/discussion-between-michael-and-johnka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\restrict[1]{\raise{-.5ex}{\big|}_{#1}}\newcommand\gra[1]{\text{graph}\kern-0.12pc\left(#1\right)}%\newcommand\restr[2]{{ \left.\kern0pc #1 \vphantom{\big|} \right|_{#2} }} \restr{f}{A} f\restrict{[0,\epsilon]}$
Any continuous function in a compact set is uniformly continuous (show it!).
This means that

$$(\forall\epsilon>0)\,(\exists\delta>0)\,(\forall x,y\in[0,1] \text{ with $|x-y|\leq\delta$})\, |f(x)-f(y)|\leq\epsilon.$$

Try to picture this.
Let $\gra{f}$ denote the graph of $f$.
Fix some $\epsilon>0$, and let $\delta$ be an associated $\delta$  obtained from uniform continuity.

We can cover the interval $[0,1]$ in $n_\delta=\left\lceil\frac1{2\delta}\right\rceil$ intervals of length $2\delta$.
Notice that $n_\delta<\frac1{2\delta}+1$.

Now, let $I$ be any such interval and $x_I\in I$ be its midpoint.
For all $y\in I$ we have $|x_I-y|<\delta$ so uniform continuity guarantees that

$$f(y)\in[f(x_I)-\epsilon,f(x_I)+\epsilon].$$

This means that $\gra{f\restrict{I}}\subset
I\times[f(x_I)-\epsilon,f(x_I)+\epsilon]$, and hence

$$\mu\left(\gra{f\restrict{I}}\right)\leq 2\delta\times2\epsilon=4\epsilon\delta.$$

Since we can cover $[0,1]$ with $n_\delta$ such intervals, we conclude that

\begin{align}
\mu\left(\gra{f}\right)
&\leq 4\epsilon\delta\cdot n_\delta\\
&\leq 4\epsilon\delta\left(\frac1{2\delta}+1\right)\\
&=2\epsilon+4\epsilon\delta\\
&\leq 6\epsilon
\end{align}

In the last step, we have used that $\delta\leq1$.
The conclusion follows.